# Out putting sum of turples from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to output the sum of turples from the a table. The SQL statement is ok and gives me results. My problem is printing the answer on a form. Below is my code:

```
<?php 
    $r=mysql_query("select sum(total_amount) from lbc_production where link_id='C741_Link01' and execution_date BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-31'");
    $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
    echo $r;
    echo $rows['(total_amount)'];              
?>
```

It outputs `Resource id #9` on a form but I want a figure.

Comment: `echo $rows['sum(total_amount)'];` or use an alias for your value

Comment: But don't echo `$r`, because it is a resource, which isn't a value that can be echoed

Comment: what are those `()` doing in `(total_amount)`? `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` and see why it's failing. Learn how to interpret syntax errors.

Comment: forget the `$r`...Try `echo $rows['total_amount'];`

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @Pedro Lobito, When I echo $rows['sum(total_amount)']; it doesn't output anything

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1. `$r` contains the resource ID for your MySQL connection. You echo it out. That's why you see that. Stop doing that and it goes away.
2. You are not using the right array key to access your sum value you seek so nothing is output. If you had error reporting turned out PHP would have told you this.

Here's improved code to resolve these issues:

```
<?php 
$r=mysql_query("select sum(total_amount) as total from lbc_production where link_id='C741_Link01' and execution_date BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-31'");
$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
echo $rows['total'];              
?>
```

I removed the line where you echo out the MySQL resource and added an alias to `sum(total_amount)` which makes it easier to access via PHP. The alias is called `total` which I use as the key to access that value from the `$row` array.

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: you may want to to replace `$rows['total']; `for `$rows['totalfrom'];`

Comment: @PedroLobito `as total`

Comment: @PedroLobito You mean change the alias I use?

Comment: `as total` looks better, it was `as totalfrom`

Comment: I always love a well-detailed explanation ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- says the guide who writes everything but the deployment guide in his answers ;)